# Загрузка картинки по ссылке в UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Помогите пожста,как засунуть картинку из интернета в UIImageView. На картинку есть ссылка:
http://realsvyaz.ru/upload/iblock/527/527d56a9964731d5955ef6f3b738cab1.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Ваш адрес"]];
imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Comment: Не самая лучшая практика.

Comment: Знаю, лучше асинхронно через NSURLConnection делать, но тогда нужно все решать в комплексе с тем где этот вид стоит, а в вопросе 
этого нет

Answer (score 0):

```
id path = @"http://realsvyaz.ru/upload/iblock/527/527d56a9964731d5955ef6f3b738cab1.jpg"; 
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path]; 
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]; 
UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]; 
self.imageView.image=img;
```